# Bing Wallpaper Downloader

Tags: firefox, rss, xml, bing

I want to use the Bing Wallpaper for my ipod Touch 5G. I know there is no app out there that can do that. Apple has not provided anyone with API's to dynamically change wallpapers off a feed or something.

So I want to create an script - preferably on a server which will read the following XML that bing gives out for its wallpaper feed:

http://www.bing.com/hpimagearchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mbl=1&mkt=en-ww

Here's how the file reads:

```
<images market="en-ww">
<image>
<startdate>20130812</startdate>
<fullstartdate>201308120000</fullstartdate>
<enddate>20130813</enddate>
<url>
/az/hprichbg/rb/SwedenFox_ROW7662255021_1366x768.jpg
</url>
<urlBase>/az/hprichbg/rb/SwedenFox_ROW7662255021</urlBase>
<mobileUrlBase>/az/hprichbg/rb/SwedenFox_ROW7662255021</mobileUrlBase>
```

The XML file has a lot more info, but for now - I need to just copy the text between `<urlBase>` and `</urlBase>` and append "bing.com" before and "_768x1366.jpg" after that text.

This will create the URL for the daily wallpaper I need in the resolution I need it.

I will need this script to run once a day and either email me the URL or save that image to my dropbox/skydrive from where I can download into my ipod and use it!

Apart from this little research, I'm an absolute noob in programming. I know little Javascript and HTML!

Please tell me what I can use to get this done!

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) might work for your needs. See for instance this recipe: [RSS To Email](https://ifttt.com/recipes/84396) (assuming of course that the wallpaper feed is available as an RSS feed).

Comment: Thanks - I can use IFTTT, but I haven't found an RSS feed for this. Even if there is, I don't know what resolution the images in the feed will be! I need 768x1366 images.

Comment: Here is the feed for the desktop images (1920x1200 I think): http://themeserver.microsoft.com/default.aspx?p=Bing&c=Desktop&m=en-US If you want it to be more legible in Google Chrome, you need to add `view-source:` to the front of the url. You can then use some other software (perhaps IFTTT?) to resize the images to your needs. I'm not sure what capabilities/server you have, but I could suggest something in a language such as bash or python, if you're up for it